# Office js EmailAddressDetails undefined recipientType for Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We use Office.js to build an Outlook web add-in and we make use of the call `composeItem.to.getAsync` where composeItem is `Office.context.mailbox.item` from opening a new compose window on Outlook. This call returns an object of the async results which has an array of the recipients. The array of recipients are of type `Office.EmailAddressDetails` and are as describe in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.emailaddressdetails?view=office-js#recipienttype).

When we do this call on windows, we get the expected array of recipients where the `EmailAddressDetails.recipientType` attribute is `"user"` or `"distributionList"` depending on what the email is.

However, when we do the same call in Mac, the same attribute is `undefined`. It is important for us to determine the `recipientType` because we use it to then call the EWS expandDL on distribution lists and then proceed to processing the email. This is 100% reproducible and we've been noticing this issue for a while now (as far back as last 8 months).

I've seen several versions on Mac. Since then, it's been happening for the last few versions and the current one. My current Mac version is **16.25 (19051201)**. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding recipientType. We are able to reproduce this issue.